# Can paternal half sisters share only 16% dna?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

My mom was adopted and knew nothing about her biological dad. We know her biological mother and her family. I'm looking for her bio dad. We both tested on Ancestry. I tested first, and I did the research with help from one of the paternal matches and narrowed it down to a particular family. There are matches on Ancestry that allows us to rule out certain males. So we ruled out 3 males due to the matches on Ancestry. They were in the 99% range for my mom's 1st cousins.

I thought I had figured out who her dad was and one of his daughters tested on Ancestry as well. Got her results and it was 1114cm 16% shared DNA. I was so sure she was my mom's half sister. My mom inherited 49% Italian from her bio dad and the person I thought was her half sister inherited 43% Italian from her bio dad.

This woman's bio dad has 4 brothers. 3 of those brother's children have tested on Ancestry, and they all show 99% 1st cousins with my mom. Brother #1's children who tested are at (they are siblings) 975cm 14% shared and 966cm 14% shared. The 2nd brother's child who tested is at 870cm 12% shared. The 3rd brother's child tested at 682cm 10% shared. The 1114cm match with the same children are brother 1 children match at 726cm and 831cm. 2nd brother child match at 1217cm and 3rd brother child 587cm.

All of the woman's bio dad's brothers are deceased. This particular match at 1114cm 16% shared DNA has 2 nieces that have tested on Ancestry, and the match my mom has with the 2 nieces are in half niece range for relationship. 1114cm match to those nieces are 1913cm 27% shared (1114cm sister is the mother) and 1722cm 25%shared (1114cm brother is father). My mom's matches to the same 2 nieces are 598cm 9% shared and 738cm 11% shared.

DNA painter shows 5% that the woman could be my mom's half sibling. I was so sure I was right on who her BD was by looking at the original matches and where they place in the family tree. I can not get it out of my head that it's a low range half sibling match.

Is it possible this is a low range half sibling match?

Comment: Does the bio dad have any known full siblings? Or maybe the BD has an unknown sibling. [DNApainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1114) says 1114cm is a good match for 1C.

Comment: Bio dad has 4 brothers. 3 of those brothers children have tested on Ancestry and they all show 99% 1st cousins with my mom. All brothers are deceased. This particular match at 1114cm 16% shared dna has 2 nieces that have tested on Ancestry and the match my mom has with the 2 nieces are in half niece range for relationship.

Comment: Can you compare the person who matches 16% with your mom to the bio dad's brother's children?

Comment: Here are the matches my mom has with 3 of the brothers children. Brother #1 children who tested are at (they are siblings) 975cm 14% shared and 966cm 14% shared. 2nd brother child that tested is at 870cm 12% shared. 3rd brother child tested at 682cm 10% shared. The 1114cm match with the same children are brother 1 children match at 726cm and 831cm. 2nd brother child match at 1217cm and 3rd brother child 587cm.

Comment: 1114cm also has 2 nieces that have tested on Ancestry. 1114cm match to those nieces are 1913cm 27% shared(1114cm sister is the mother) and 1722cm 25%shared( 1114cm brother is father). My mom's matches to the same 2 nieces are 598cm 9% shared and 738cm 11%shared.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I've tried modifying it but it won't let me. Sorry

Comment: I've tried to edit in the information from the comments.